# Whether it is possible to get the text of a drop-list instead of its value using PHP?

Tags: php

Whether it is possible to **get the Text** of a HTML `<select>` list **instead of its value** using PHP?

For example from the given below HTML code

Code:

`<option value='1'>January</option>`

I want to get the text `"January"`, if it is possible then how?

I cant use `"January"` for both text as well as value of drop-down because both are for different purpose.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi there is a solution. but you would have to use ajax

onsubmit, use javascript to capture the text from the drop down list. pass this text to php using ajax. that should do the trick =)

Answer (score 4):

No. If there is a `value` attribute (and there should always be one), the browser will only submit the `value` as value. There's nothing PHP can do, since the browser simply does not send the information.

If you are creating the list though, you should be able to figure out that the value `1` corresponds to "January", hence this is usually not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, only the value is sent to the server.  However, you can maintain a mapping and use that when processing the form.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use JQuery to update a hidden input field with the text value of the selected element when the form submits.

Answer (score 1):

In short: no it's not.

But you can have an associative array to match the month given the number. ;)

Answer (score 1):

what i suggest is that. u can just create a hidden field. and by using js u can get the selected text and then store the value in this hidden field .then collect the value from this hidden field using html/php